# WCF REST client parameter encoding

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I am consuming a REST service (actually a php page, which renders XML) from .NET.

As the HttpRequest approach looks really awful, I've tried to build a WCF client for this service, but I ran into a problem, my URI template looks like this:

```
page.php?product={productType}
```

And the productType parameter is a string, which may contain (and does contain in most cases) non-ASCII characters. As far as I understand, WCF encodes parameters with UTF-8 by default, but it seems that the service, which I am consuming (and which I have no  control over, as it is from a 3rd party), is trying to decode those parameters with another, windows-1257, encoding.

So the question is - can I somehow change the encoding, that is used by the WCF to encode the parameter values?

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to try and use the WCF Client to access non WCF services.  Not even to access WCF REST services!  Go look for the HTTPClient that is included in the http://wcf.codeplex.com project.  It's much easier to use than HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Why not? I mean any arguments would be great in here, as I'm already successfully connecting to ASMX services with WCF, and this connection to REST service is also partly successful (it would be fully successfull, if the service would be working in UTF-8)